# php exec inside exec / nested exec

Tags: php, apache, permissions, exec

If I'm already running code in a background by exec
and inside it I call for another exec.

Is it possible ?
If so, does it need special permissions ?

The error I have (and I suspect nested exec in it):

```
exec() has been disabled for security reasons
```

Regular exec enabled and works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically it's possible to have an exec in your exec, but it looks like you're using different configurations. Usually PHP has to different sets (Apache and CLI) of php.ini files (which might be configured to disable the exec function at all.

I assume your first exec call is coming from apache, which then calls a php script on the command line. The second seems to have a different configuration and therefore disallow the exec-call. So best have a look at /etc/php, if there are different php.inis set.

Comment: Thanks for reply Tobi,

We have only one set of php.ini in our servers.
Also simple checks like:

// php
if(exec('echo EXEC') == 'EXEC'){
    echo 'exec works';
}

Shows that exec working properly from command line.

I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share your code.... It is difficult to determinate if there is any problem without looking the code.
If you have access to use `exec` it should not be a problem to use `exec` inside another `exec`.
This is your localhost or a shared hosting? Most shared hosting disable exec for security reasons.